# How do I load fonts into my project using webpack?

Tags: css, fonts, webpack

I have a project using webpack and I am trying to load fonts into my scss. My base.scss file is trying to load the fonts in like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'League Spartan';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/assets/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.svg#league_spartanbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

My webpack config is currently set up like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const PATHS = {
  dist: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
  src: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
  style: path.join(__dirname,'/src/assets/stylesheets')
}

const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
process.env.BABEL_ENV = TARGET;
exports.TARGET = TARGET;

var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index'
  ],
  resolve: {
    extenstion: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.dist,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['babel?cacheDirectory'],
        include: PATHS.src
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html-loader",
        include: PATHS.src
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000000",
        include: PATHS.src
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg/,
        loader: 'svg-url-loader',
        include: PATHS.src
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        include: PATHS.src
      },
      {
        test:   /\.scss$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader",
        include: PATHS.src
      },
      {
        test:   /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader",
        include: PATHS.src
      },
      {
          test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          loader: "file-loader",
          include: PATHS.src
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: PATHS.dist,
    hot: true,
    historyAPIFallback: true,
    inline: true,
    progress: true,
    stats: 'errors-only'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

My project builds as expected but the fonts don't appear to have loaded at all. I am not sure if the issue is the path I am using for the fonts, although I have tested this theory by changing the path of the font in the css file `src: url('/fakepath/wontwork/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.eot');` and webpack fails to find it and won't build, so it does appear like the path is working.

Comment: What does your style/css webpack configurations look like? What is it using?

Comment: on a practical note: stop using font formats that are "not WOFF". Webfont support has moved on since FontSquirrel and friends started, and they are not keeping up with the times: `eot` and `svg` are deprecated and abandoned (literally. Spec's been discontinued, it was a terrible idea), respectively. And, as WOFF is a byte-for-byte wrapper around arbitrary `ttf` and `otf` opentype fonts, there is no reason to do both WOFF (specifically meant for web deploys) *and* the equivalent plain font. Make your life easier: just use WOFF.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans interesting info I wasn't aware of. Honestly the only reason I tried including these types is because I was told to. Which in hindsight isn't a good way to make a decision, but I wasn't aware of what you said. I will keep this in mind for future projects and I appreciate the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your paths relative - the css loader [does not treat absolute paths as webpack resources](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#root-relative-urls).

> For urls that start with a `/`, the default behavior is to not translate them:
>
> ```
> url(/image.png) => url(/image.png)
> ```