# Custom fonts with sass-loader and Webpack & having fonts in source and dist

Tags: fonts, webpack, sass, font-face, sass-loader

#### The (*original*) problem

*I managed to get the fonts to work but my folder structure is pretty weird now and needs fixing. Scroll down to [edit] for the current problem.*

My problem is that I can't get my Webpack workflow setup to take custom fonts I want to use from the include `url("path/to/my/font.ttf")` in my Sass / .scss file.

In case you want to try my config, here is my barebones workflow (develop branch): https://github.com/EddyVinck/Webpack-Workflow/tree/develop

#### Here is what I want to happen, but feel free to point out better alternatives:

- Have my included fonts in my Sass files moved to `dist/assets/fonts`
- make sure the path is configured correctly in my dist folder's `main.css`
- actually be able to use my custom fonts when developing and not having to change or move files when I want to deploy.

#### What I tried:

1. changing the path in my font-face and using `require()` in `src/js/main.js` but I learned that the path is relative to the compiled css file so I can't do this.

Conclusion: the src:url() has to be like this because Webpack will complain if I set it relative to the font in `/src`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "open-sans";
    src: url("/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

2. the solution offered here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/411#issuecomment-296491200 did not work for me
3. I also looked into posts here on SO like https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader and [How do I load fonts into my project using webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077968/how-do-i-load-fonts-into-my-project-using-webpack) but without success.
4. probably dozens of other posts/articles by now.

#### Possible solutions which I haven't figured out yet how to do

- https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader
- https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin

If anyone could help me fix this then you would have made my day. I can't for the life of me figure out how to solve this problem. Once again my Github repository is pretty barebones and is meant just to setup a workflow, but not being able to use and see custom fonts when developing is a real bummer.

## [edit] Changing the file-loader path (current problem)

I managed to get my fonts to work in the webpack-dev-server by removing the `/` in front of the path in `_fonts.scss` because [sass-loader does not resolve paths that start with /](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#root-relative-urls) and by changing the path in my webpack configuration to `'[path][name].[ext]'`. This, however, results in having a pretty bad path in my dist folder like `dist/src/assets/thirdparty/googlefonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf` and right now I have not figured out how to set up the files as `dist/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf` while also being able to render the fonts in the webpack-dev-server.
To make sure my fonts are copied to the dist folder I did the following:

```
// index.js
require("../css/includes/_fonts.scss");
```

*Mods, please don't mark this as a duplicate. Other posts haven't been of help to me so I don't think my problem is a duplicate.*

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: 'main.css'
})

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') //,
        // publicPath: '/dist'
    },
    module: {
    rules: 
        [
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" 
            },
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader:'pug-loader',
                        options: {
                            pretty: true
                        }
                    }                   
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractPlugin.extract({
                    use: ['css-loader','sass-loader']
                })              
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'img/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },      
    plugins: [
        extractPlugin,
        //// actual templates
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/templates/index.pug",
            favicon: "src/img/ecmascript6.png",
            filename: "index.html"
        }), 
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/templates/test.pug",
            favicon: "src/img/ecmascript6.png",
            filename: "test.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: did you fix this? I have same problem...

Comment: @IvanCoronado It's been a while since I worked on this, but I think this should work: https://github.com/EddyVinck/Webpack-Workflow/blob/master/webpack.config.js by the way, this is a webpack 3 issue, and it might have been fixed or made easier to do in Webpack 4.